# Issue with Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring 3.2.2. I was trying to  reload the resource bundle at runtime using the spring provided facility ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.But it seems that  it is not working as expected. I have created the below standalone java application example for the same.

Please find the below application context xml file and source code of the example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:standard</value>
                <value>com/springinterlocalization/format</value>
                <value>file:/D:/Jinesh/jinesh.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * @author Krunali
 *
 */
public class TestSpringInterLocalization {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springinterlocalization/springinternationalizationcontext.xml");
        System.out.println(ctx.getMessage("jinesh.thirdtest", null, null));
        System.out.println("Updating the properties file");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\workspace\\SpringExamples\\src\\standard.properties");
            fos.write("jinesh.latestaddproperty=this is the newly added property."
                .getBytes("UTF-8"));
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("going to sleep for 10 secs while the bundles are reloaded");
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        System.out.println(ctx.getMessage("jinesh.latestaddproperty", null, null));

    }

}
```

In the above example i tried to add the **jinesh.latestaddproperty** to the properties file in the classpath **standard.properties** file but it seems that the property is added to the property file but spring is not able to pick up that change and giving the below error.

```
Oct 28, 2013 12:46:13 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@75dc818d: startup date [Mon Oct 28 00:46:13 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 28, 2013 12:46:13 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/springinterlocalization/springinternationalizationcontext.xml]
Oct 28, 2013 12:46:14 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6af7de45: defining beans [messageSource]; root of factory hierarchy
Updating the properties file
going to sleep for 10 secs while the bundles are reloaded
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'jinesh.latestaddproperty' for locale 'null'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234)
    at com.springinterlocalization.TestSpringInterLocalization.main(TestSpringInterLocalization.java:37)
```

I just want to know why spring is not able to pick the change and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the classpath specific properties file is being cached by the jvm and so Spring will not see any change in the properties file to reload again.

Instead refer to an absolute file and retry your test with the properties file outside of the classpath and you should see your test work correctly.

Reference: from [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html):

> Since application servers typically cache all files loaded from the
>   classpath, it is necessary to store resources somewhere else (for
>   example, in the "WEB-INF" directory of a web app). Otherwise changes
>   of files in the classpath will not be reflected in the application.

and

> With a "classpath:" prefix, resources can still be loaded from the
>   classpath, but "cacheSeconds" **values other than "-1" (caching forever)**
>   **will not work in this case**.

Comment: Thanks biju for your answer but spring is not able to read from the file in the absolute path as well. I have added the simple property in that file(jinesh.propeties) but spring is not able to read any property from that file. Any idea ?

Comment: I think the issue with absolute file is that the extension need not be specified, so just specify the basename as `file:/D:/Jinesh/jinesh` not `file:/D:/Jinesh/jinesh.properties`. Also, I tried locally with a similar set up as yours and I am seeing the property change.

Comment: I am still facing the same issue even after removing the .properties extension. I am not able to read any of the property specified in the  file file:/D:/Jinesh/jinesh. Do you have any idea why this is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Biju said in his answer regarding `.properties` extension, there should be no slash between `file:` and `D:`.

Result:

```
<bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:standard</value>
                <value>com/springinterlocalization/format</value>
                <value>file:D:/Jinesh/jinesh</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```